# Apache not executing a 'do' include function in included perl script

Tags: apache, perl

Apache 2.4 has been configured for Server Side Includes and correctly runs any CGI script passed as long as the variables are local. However, we have a few scripts that use a 'do' function to pull in variables from a configuration file, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
do '../includes/cgi.conf';
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print $hostname
```

cgi.conf contains the following:

```
$host = 'none.nowhere.com';
```

When executed at the command line on the webserver, the variable populates into the output as expected. However, Apache will not print it as expected unless the variable is declared locally in the script.

I am upgrading an application from RHEL6/Apache 2.2 to RHEL7/Apache 2.4 and this configuration worked previously, so I may have missed something in the upgrade to new configuration.

Please excuse any typos in code blocks. Code was not copy pasted and any typos do not exist in the actual code.

Comment: (Aside) "Please excuse any typos in code blocks." - _You_ need to ensure there are no typos in the code before posting; you only have 5 lines?! Typos in code snippets in questions are a huge source of confusion.

Comment: You are loading the variable `$host` and you are printing the variable `$hostname`. It is not the same variable.

Comment: The variable was correct in the actual code, that was a typo in manually copying it to here. I solved my issue by adding additional permissions to the conf file.

Answer (score 1):

The `do` reads a file and executes (`eval`s) it as Perl code. If that fails, nothing happens (silently). It's like ignoring an `eval`.

`require` is like `do` but complains if there was a problem (the perldoc entry shows the actual behavior). You should `require` the file so it can tell you that something didn't happen. Or, at least, check the result of `do` and send `$@` to the error log if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming the current directory is set to the directory containing the script.

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

do "$RealBin/../includes/cgi.conf";
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by adding read permissions for the apache user to the configuration file. It had execute permissions only from the old server and I had assumed that was all it needed on the new server.